# How to get data after DataView filtering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

I apply a filter to Dataview and after that I need to get the filtered data.
before filtering I did:

```
dvUnloadOpenAccounts.RowFilter = "uso_id = '30640'";
foreach (DataRow row in dvUnloadOpenAccounts.Table.Rows)
{
   HSSFRow dataRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
   foreach (DataColumn column in dvUnloadOpenAccounts.Table.Columns)
   {
       dataRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal).SetCellValue(row[column].ToString());
   }
   rowIndex++;
}
```

So I need do the same with filtered data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assign a Filtered `DataView` to your `DataTable`, then you can iterate your `DataTable`.

```
dtbl = dvUnloadOpenAccounts.ToTable();
//Then iterate your DataTable
```